# I retrieved some pictures and texts form the firebase into a Recycler, the texts are shown and retrieved correctly but the images are not

Tags: java, android, firebase

Here, I want to Retrieve the image and text into a RecyclerView which is the ImageActivity: here is its XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
tools:context=".ImagesActivity">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The ImagesActivity Java class: Here I want to set the data into the RecyclerView using OnBindViewHolder from ImageAdapter Activity.

```
   public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }
                mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ImageAdapterActiviy Java Class which retrive the data from firebase using OnBindeViewHolder:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }
    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }
    }

}
```

Upload Java Class: here the setter and getter method.

```
public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed some unimportant files. now if you can help me.

Comment: What does "uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()" return? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).